# Change image resolution when exporting png with plotly.js backend

Tags: plot, julia, plotly.js, plots.jl

How can I change size of output png when plotting in Julia with plotlyjs backend?

Here is my code:

```
plotlyjs()
a = [1,2,3]; b = [1,2,3];
p = scatter(a, b);
plot!(p, size=(500, 500))
savefig(p, "test.png")
```

Julia plot window is 500x500 but exported png is 500x700. I have tried `savefig(p, "test.png", width=500, height=500)`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following:

```
using PlotlyJS
a = [1,2,3]; b = [1,2,3];
p = plot(scatter(;x=a, y=b))
savefig(p, "test.png", width=500, height=500)
```

The main issue was that p wasn't a plot (but a trace for a scatter) in my case.